# only edit certain fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a user model that has fields for first_name, last_name, email, and password.  After a user signs up under their user profile page I would like to allow certain fields and not others to show on a form to update part of the user info.

For example I would like just the first_name to be shown as a field when I render a form for them to edit their name.  How do I handle this?  Should I make a new route and a controller action that lets me update just this one field?  or do I just hide all the other fields and submit them in the background without the user seeing them?

```
<div class="signup_user">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 centered">

      <%= form_for(@user) do |form| %>

      <%= render "shared/errors", object: @user %>
      <%= render "shared/flash" %>

        <div class="card card-default">
          <div class="card-body">

            <h1>Create account</h1>  

            <%= form.label :first_name %>
            <%= form.text_field :first_name, size: 40, autofocus: true, class: "required form-control" %>              

            <%= form.label :last_name %>
            <%= form.text_field :last_name, size: 40, class: "required form-control" %>

            <%= form.label :email %>
            <%= form.email_field :email, size: 40, class: "required form-control" %>

            <%= form.label :password %>
            <%= form.password_field :password, size: 40,  placeholder: "At least 10 characters", class: "required form-control" %>

            <%= form.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
            <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40, class: "required form-control" %><br>

            <%= form.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-block btn-outline-primary' %>

           <% end %>

           <hr>
           <p>Already have an account? <%= link_to "Sign In", new_session_path %></p>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><!--./container-->
</div><!--./signup_user-->
```

after the initial signup I would like to just show 1 field like this for editing just the user name.

```
<div class="signup_user">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 centered">

          <%= form_for(@user) do |form| %>

          <%= render "shared/errors", object: @user %>
          <%= render "shared/flash" %>

            <div class="card card-default">
              <div class="card-body">


                <%= form.label :first_name %>
                <%= form.text_field :first_name, size: 40, autofocus: true, class: "required form-control" %>              



        </div>
      </div><!--./container-->
    </div><!--./signup_user-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is use the action_name helper and create some conditional logic that will conditionally render the fields that you only want to show on the new action, e.g. `action_name == "new"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd make two definitions of strong parameters on the controller:

```
def create_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
end

def update_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
end
```

Then in your `create`/`update` methods just allow each different definition. You don't need a new view or a new model if you just restrict the params based on the action.

```
def create
  @user.create(create_params)
  redirect_to users_path
end

def update
  @user.update_attributes(update_params)
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

Makes sense to me, and that way you don't have to create anything superfluous. Then fields will be rejected in a secure way the way they should be. Then you can adjust the view with `action_name == 'edit'` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate an additional view by creating a **new model**.

**Example :**

**models/user_edit.rb**

```
class User_Edit < User
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...
end
```

**routes**

```
  resources :users
  devise_for :users, path: 'users', controllers: {
        sessions:           "users/sessions",
        passwords:          "users/passwords",
        registrations:      "users/registrations",
        confirmations:      "users/confirmations",
      }
  devise_for :users_edit, path: 'users_edit', controllers: {
        registrations:      "users_edit/registrations",
      }
```

**And so you will have :**

```
views/users/registrations/edit.html
```

**and**

```
views/users_edit/registrations/edit.html
```

Comment: When he wants to edit a single object then why would he require a new model?